# Is Transversality invariant by losing Dimension?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, characteristic-classes

**Setup** Let $X$ be a smooth, reduced and irreducible scheme. And let $E$ be a vector bundle of rank $n$ on $X$. Following Eisenbud and Harris we say that the collection $\{\sigma_1,...,\sigma_k\}$ of sections of $E$ is dimensionally transverse if $codim_X(V(\sigma_1\wedge ...\wedge \sigma_k))=n-k+1$.

Here $V(\sigma_1\wedge ...\wedge \sigma_k):=\{x\in X:\sigma_1(x)\wedge...\wedge\sigma_k(x)=0\}$, i.e. it is the degeneracy locus of the collection of sections. By a theorem of Macaulay we know that the codimension above is, in any case, at most $n-k+1$. Moreover if the codimension is $n-k+1$, then it is pure, i.e. any connected component has the same codimension.

The construction above is motivated by the fact that if we have such a collection of sections, then we can define the $k$-th Chern Class of $E$ by $c_k(E)=[V(\sigma_1\wedge...\wedge\sigma_k)]$.

> Eisenbud and Harris claim that if we have a collection of $n$
>   dimensionally transverse sections of $E$ then we can define the Total
>   Chern Class of $E$: $c(E)=1+c_1(E)+...+c_n(E)$. In specific it means
>   that **if we have a collection of $n$ dimensionally transverse
>   sections, then we can find a collection of $k$ dimensionally
>   transverse sections for any $k\leq n$.**
>
> Unfortunately I don't see how to prove (or disprove) it, may you
>   please help?

**Advancement** I tried to prove that cutting out a section from a collection of dimensionally transverse sections would give a collection of dimensionally transverse sections. But, though I don't have a counterexample, it does not seem to be the case.

Moreover it is easy to observe that, if there is a counterexample to the sentence in bold, then the vector bundle must not be globally generated.

**Edit** This is the restyling of a question which didn't appear, in my opinion, to receive enough attention. If you have any constructive criticism or suggestion on how to improve it I would be very glad to receive them!

Thank you for your time!